# Fill JS DataTable with conditions - Entity Framework MVC5

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have an MV5 project with C#, EF and SQL Server, and I'm filling a data table (from datatables.net references) using the following code:

```
public ActionResult GetData()
{
   using (Entity db = new Entity())
   {
      List<tableName> htmlTable = db.tableName.ToList<tableName>();
      return Json(new { data = htmltable }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
}
```

That brings the entire table, but I'm looking to filter these based on user session (so userX "selects" only the rows that he manages or where the columnY has any filter) so it runs a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE idUser = 'userX' AND columnY = 1;
```

Can I bind data to the DataTable with filters adapting the method above or I have to change the data-bind approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try as shown in the below query. Here is a [Basic LINQ Query Operations (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/basic-linq-query-operations)
 reference learning to you.

```
public ActionResult GetData()
{
  using (Entity db = new Entity())
  {
     var htmltable = (from r in db.tableName WHERE r.idUser == "userX" &&
     r.columnY = 1
     select r).ToList();
     return Json(new { data = htmltable }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add filter on tableName with the help of linq and lambda expression

Ex:

```
var htmlTable = db.tableName.Where(d=>d.idUser=="userX" && 
columnY==1).ToList<tableName>();
```